# Print Composer Reference map

Tags: qgis, georeferencing, print-composer

Recently started using QGIS 2.18, for basic mapping.
I am using Swedish GEO-agancy data shapefiles as bottom layers with my own shapefiles as toplayers (**EPSG:3006 (SWEREF99 TM)**), including a GPX file (**EPSG:4326 (WGS84)**) manipulated by GPXeditor.

When using the Print Composer to export the map as a GeoTIFF I can not choose a "**Reference Map**" under "Composition -> Export Settings".

So the exported TIF does not include any georeferencing when opening it in ex. Avenza on my phone.
Also the map on my phone is already 2/3 zoomed in, I can't see an overview by zooming out. I can zoom in though.

All coordinates match up in the QGIS project window with the **EPSG:3006** system, even the GPX waypoints that are Google Maps system coordinated **EPSG:4326 (WGS84)**.[image]

Why can't I set a Reference Map ?
Is it because all layers are **EPSG3006** exept the GPX waypoints that are **EPSG:4326**?

Or is there some other reasone the map does not export a GeoTIFF.

Comment: As far as I remember, the dropdown box of `Referenzkarte` is only filled if you have more than  one map in your print composition.

Comment: Yes that is logical :)
But then the one map I have should be defaulted in the dropdown menu when no other is available.

Comment: I think it's a bug
https://issues.qgis.org/issues/16796

Comment: If you export the map canvas from Project > Save As Image you get a geo-referenced image output.  If you export from Composer using Composer > Save As Image you get a non geo-referenced image unless you check the option to Save World File under Export settings.  And the empty reference map dropdown is still blank in 2.18.12 even with more than one map in the composer.

Comment: how could you set a reference map with out a second map to refer to? see http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/making_a_map.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you export the map canvas from `Project > Save As Image` you get a geo-referenced image output.

If you export from Composer using `Composer > Save As Image` you get a non geo-referenced image unless you check the option to **Save World File** under Export settings.  However, I cannot get QGIS 2.18.12 (Windows 7 x64) to write a world file with Composer output.  This has been reported before in QGIS 2.16 (https://issues.qgis.org/issues/15268) and was fixed but this may be a regression in 2.18.  It might work in QGIS on Linux or OSX.

[aside: the empty reference map dropdown is still blank in my 2.18.12 even with more than one map in the composer.]

[image]

See the docs [here](http://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/create_output.html#export-as-image) and [here](http://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/overview_composer.html#export-settings) for more info on how to set this up.

Comment: Ok thanks for the info! 
Was hoping for a solution to the Composer way of doing this as i can control the resolution output...
Will wait for the fix!

Comment: So actually when I export from the Project Window, my TIF file is not Geo-Referenced. Within the file itself.
When importing it to Avenza Maps on my phone it warns med that the map has no reference.

It does however export a TFW file. Which Avenza cant handle.

So I understand now that my export from the Composer has a reference, but the coordinates are all wrong compared to the ones in the Project window where i am working.

Strange...

Comment: And, thankfully, this will all be fixed in the next point release as Nyall said.

Answer (score 2):

This was bug https://issues.qgis.org/issues/16924, which will be fixed in the next point release (2.18.13).